# How to combine different cells according to the customer ID?

Tags: python, r, excel

I have a transaction data set and I want to transform this according to the customer ID. the sample is given below.

```
CustomerID    Description

17850         WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER
17850         WHITE METAL LANTERN
13047         ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT
13047         POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM
13047         POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN
```

I want this data set in  the following order:-

```
17850         WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER, WHITE METAL LANTERN
13047         ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT,POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM, POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN
```

The dataset is in csv format and each value in separate cell.
can anyone suggest any method to do this in excel or R or python?

Comment: For code and data, please indent four spaces so it stands out. I've done this for you in this case, so you can see the difference.

Comment: thank you sir for the formatting of question. can you suggest me some easy way to achieve the desired format of my data. there are more than 10 thousands datapoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` function, Created my own data, you can do this for your own data frame above. Based on `Customer` number, the `Texts` are concatenated

```
> df <- data.frame(Customer = c(1,1,2,3,3,4), Texts = c("AAA","aaa","BBB","bbb","CCC","ccc"))
> df
   Customer Texts
1        1   AAA
2        1   aaa
3        2   BBB
4        3   bbb
5        3   CCC
6        4   ccc


> aggregate(Texts~Customer,toString,data=df)
     Customer    Texts
 1          1 AAA, aaa
 2          2      BBB
 3          3 bbb, CCC
 4          4      ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/tutorials.html).

Install it, then try

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the cvs file
df = pd.read_csv('yourFileName.csv')

# Group by CustomerID and join Descriptions with commas
df.groupby('CustomerID')['Description'].apply(','.join)

# Save the result in cvs file
df.to_csv('resultFileName.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

other ways to do this include using `plyr` and `data.table`. data.table is probably more efficient, simple and as well offers control.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID), summarize, Text = paste(Text, collapse = ","))
```

or

```
require(DT)
DT <- data.table(df)
# group the table by ID and then add a new column by pasting the list 
# of values in each group together. 

DT[, list(Text = paste(Text, collapse = ",")), by = ID]

   ID                                                                                Text
1: 17850                              WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,WHITE METAL LANTERN
2: 13047  ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT,POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM, POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN
```

Data

---

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(17850,17850,13047,13047,13047),
      Text = c("WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER","WHITE METAL LANTERN",
              " ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT","POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE BEDROOM",
              " POPPY'S PLAYHOUSE KITCHEN"))
```